# How strong is the state-of-the-art in real-world "implicit authentication" systems?

Tags: authentication, mobile

Years ago, I read [a paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotsec09/tech/full_papers/jakobsson.pdf) about how mobile devices made it possible to authenticate users without entering a password, simply by relying on behavior, habits, locations. Now, the [DoD plans to use such authentication mechanisms](http://federalnewsradio.com/defense/2016/06/dod-plans-bring-cac-cards-end/) for their own network security. However, I haven't seen any apps that use this widely.

I guess I have two questions:

1) Are there any real-world examples of such behavioral/implicit authentication systems that justifies the DoD's faith in using this for parts of their network?

2) If no, then what has prevented them from being more widely used-- is it because human behavior is unpredictable and this leads to false negatives (why not use passwords as a backup)?  Or is it because of the privacy implications of such a scheme? Surely, we all hate typing passwords on our phone screens...

Comment: Looks like they plan to use it as *one factor* on a multifactor authentication scheme. That is much different from using it as *an* authentication scheme.

Comment: True. But, most of the literature uses it in exactly the same way-- *as the first authentication factor *, backing off and requiring passwords in case of any sensitive access requirements or if the identification certainty is below a particular threshold. This is different from "traditional 2FA" where both factors are always used. I'm just surprised that the DoD is the first large-scale adopter of something like this, since I haven't seen it being used anywhere else.